# ROR: DB relation serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, relationship

I have a model which has a relation:

```
class buildings
has_many :floors
end

class floors
belong_to :buildings
has_many :rooms
end

class rooms
belong_to :floors
end
```

and serializers as

```
class BuildingsSerializer < ActiveModelSerializers::Model
  attributes :building_name
  has_many :floor
end

class FloorsSerializer < ActiveModelSerializers::Model
  attributes :floor_name
  belongs_to :building
  has_many :room
end

class RoomsSerializer < ActiveModelSerializers::Model
  attributes :room_name
  belongs_to :floor
end
```

So when i query as `Building.includes(:floor)all` the FE is getting

```
[
   {
      building_name: "building_one",
      floor: [
         {
            floor_name: "floor_one"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

the room serializer is not showing. I wanted the returned json which also includes the room detais. The response should include building info, floor info and also room info by queering from Building table, but as of now i am only getting the buinding and floor information. Expected result:

```
[
   {
      building_name: "building_one",
      floor: [
         {
            floor_name: "floor_one",
            room: [
                {
                    room_name: "room_one"
                }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Thank You

Comment: Can you add the query you use to get building, floor and room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`belongs_to` associations must use the singular term.
The name of the model should be pluralized when declaring a `has_many` association.

First correct the typo in associations:

```
# In Building serializer
has_many :floor  to   has_many :floors

# In Floor serializer
has_many :room   to   has_many :rooms
```

Also frontend query should be as below:

```
Building.includes(floor: :rooms).all
```

You can add below changes in serializer and check:

```
class BuildingSerializer < ActiveModelSerializers::Model
  attributes :building_name
  attribute :floors

 def floors 
   ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(object.floors, serializer: FloorSerializer)
  end
end

class FloorSerializer < ActiveModelSerializers::Model
  attributes :floor_name
  belongs_to :building
  attribute :rooms

  def rooms 
   ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(object.rooms, serializer: RoomSerializer)
  end
end

class RoomSerializer < ActiveModelSerializers::Model
  attributes :room_name
  belongs_to :floor
end
```

Comment: thanks for the anser... it works but the problem is it keeps queering from database every time it fetch for rooms.

Comment: Please change this `Building.includes(floor: :rooms, ).all` to `Building.includes(:floor, :rooms).all`